# How does a clickableRow work with passing data in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view that will display a table and each row in the table is setup as a "clickableRow" which I point to a controller which will point to the new view, my question is how do I pass the information from that clickable row so I can utilize it in the next view/controller.
For example:

```
foreach (var item in Model.results)                         
{                                       
Html.AntiForgeryToken();
<tr class="clickableRow" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("InstructorCourseDetailView", "Course")'">
     <td>@Html.Encode(item.courseName)</td>
     <td>@Html.Encode(item.courseNumber)</td>
     <td>@Html.Encode(item.courseInstructor)</td>
     <td>@Html.Encode(item.courseSchedule)</td>
</tr>
}
```

I want to take that particular item and pass it to a view that will display all of that particular course's information which was found with a database query. I would think it would do something with passing that course's "courseID" to the controller..
I'm just not sure how this works or if there is maybe a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a third parameter to the Url.Action, it will contains the data that you would like to send to the next control.

```
@Url.Action("InstructorCourseDetailView", "Course", new { item.courseID })
```

Comment: That makes sense.. but then how does that work on the controller side of things? Would it be like..
public ActionResult InstructorCourseDetailView(int courseID)
?

Comment: Yes. Exactly like that.